# Django: redirect the user from the login page if he has already logged in

Tags: python, django

I want to redirect the user from the login page if he is already logged in;
this means that the user who logged in will no longer have access to the login page.
the login page looks something like this:
example.com/login

this is my code in view.py:

```py
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            logIn(request, user)
            return redirect('/')

        else:
            messages.info(request, 'username or password is wrong')
    context = {}

    return render(request, 'account/login.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code as a reference:

```
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect("/")
```

Comment: This error is shown: TypeError at / login /
'bool' object is not callable

Comment: this is true:
`if request.user.is_authenticated:` i think

Answer (score 0):

Your views seems okay besides some couple typos. Just add an extra control statement to top of your `login` view something like:

```py
def login(request):
    # Logged in users will be redirected to 'home' page
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('home')
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ....
```

Comment: But I think you forgot the `return`

Comment: But this applies to everyone, not just users who are logged in

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to add `return`. Also function based views are okey but in order to keep your code DRY class based views are strongly recommended.